# How to Send a Form to the Server Without Interfering with PayPal Smart Buttons

Tags: php, paypal

I'm attempting to send an order confirmation email when the PayPal payment processing is approved. I believe the problem lies in the fact that when I submit my form, the page refreshes and when the PayPal payment is approved it also refreshes the page. The PHP code works fine for what I need it for at the moment and so does the PayPal Smart Buttons, the main problem is they'll only ever work separately and I need both to execute. I've been looking around for awhile and haven't been able to find a specific solution to this problem, but maybe I just haven't seen them.

I thought of using AJAX to submit my form without refreshing, but I'll admit I'm pretty new to that kind of stuff, and the code I added didn't seem to make much of a difference.

```
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {

    // Get the order details
    return actions.order.get().then(function (orderDetails) {

            
            $(function () {

            $( "#ppCheckoutForm" ).on('submit', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
            url: '/OrderConfirmation.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#ppCheckoutForm').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('Form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
      
            document.getElementById("ppCheckoutForm").submit();

            
      document.querySelector('#confirm-button')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {


          return actions.order.capture().then(function () {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your code above, inside the onApprove you should immediately *run* your ajax function, not bind an event handler to a submit button.

If you were to be binding such an event handler to a submit button (different, separate solution, which is not what you need), that button would need something to prevent its default action of redirecting.

---

The best solution is to submit all your data in an ajax/fetch call and have this action itself trigger a capture *on the server side*.

Here is the JavaScript code to use for the approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You'll need two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction', and one for 'Capture Transaction', [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/)

When your JavaScript does the 'Capture Transaction', you'll be sending your form data along with the orderId to capture, and your server should persist that form data in your data base if and only if it is able to do a successful capture (via API).